# Nginx Rewrite Rule Query String redirect

Tags: nginx

I want when someone requests this url

> http://domain.com/5.ts?u=admin:p=123

to go to

> /file.php?id=5&username=admin&p=123

I did that

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\.ts\?u=(.*)\:p=(.*)$ /file.php?id=$1&username=$2&password=$3 break;
```

But no sure, why that isn't working

Comment: How about turn rewrite_log on and check logs

Comment: It says that 5.ts doesn't exists, which means the rewrite rule is VALID as rule, but not the correct one for my job......